# SQL Nested Inner Joins

Tags: mysql

Im trying to use the results of an inner join in another query and having trouble getting my head around how.

This is the first query i am running:

```
SELECT projects.Project_ID, projects.Name
FROM projects
INNER JOIN assigned_users
ON assigned_users.Project_ID=projects.Project_ID AND assigned_users.User_ID=4;
```

This is getting all of the assigned projects for a particular user. The Project_ID's this query returns i want to use to find all the related requirements for those projects.

```
SELECT *
FROM requirements
WHERE requirements.Project_ID=1;
```

So instead of finding the requirements for project '1' i want to get the requirements for all projects assigned to a particular user. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would just add another `JOIN`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM assigned_users au JOIN
     projects p
     ON au.Project_ID = p.Project_ID JOIN
     requirements r
     ON r.Project_ID = p.Project_ID
WHERE au.User_ID = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

```
SELECT *
FROM requirements req
INNER JOIN projects pro 
    ON req.Project_ID = pro.Project_ID
INNER JOIN assigned_users u
    ON u.Project_ID=pro.Project_ID
WHERE u.User_ID=4;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM requirements
WHERE requirements.Project_ID=(
    SELECT Project_ID
    FROM projects
    INNER JOIN assigned_users
    ON assigned_users.Project_ID=projects.Project_ID AND assigned_users.User_ID=4;
);
```

Comment: This worked thank you!. The second one didn't work when more than 1 row was return but the first one did so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To the existing query, we can just add:

```
  JOIN requirements
    ON requirements.Project_ID = projects.Project_ID
```

We add expressions to the SELECT list to retrieve values of columns from requirements.

```
SELECT projects.Project_ID, projects.Name
     , requirements.some_column
     , requirements.some_other_column
```

It's likely that we also want to add an `ORDER BY` clause so that the rows are returned in a predictable sequence.

Note that if there are no matching rows in `requirements` for a given `Project_ID`, then that project will not be returned. To return those rows, we can specify an outer join.

Current query:

```
SELECT projects.Project_ID
     , projects.Name
  FROM projects
  JOIN assigned_users
    ON assigned_users.Project_ID=projects.Project_ID
   AND assigned_users.User_ID=4
```

Proposed query with outer join to `requirements` table:

```
SELECT projects.Project_ID
     , projects.Name
     , requirements.Requirement_ID
     , requirements.Requirement_Name 
  FROM projects
  JOIN assigned_users
    ON assigned_users.Project_ID=projects.Project_ID
   AND assigned_users.User_ID=4
  LEFT
  JOIN requirements 
    ON requirements.Project_ID = projects.Project_ID
 ORDER
    BY projects.Project_ID
     , requirements.Requirement_ID
```

Equivalently, we could relocate the condition `assigned_users.User_ID=4` from the `ON` clause of the inner join to a `WHERE` clause, before the `ORDER BY`.